# How can you hide the Tumblr App buttons on iPhone?

Tags: ios, css, iphone, hide, tumblr

I have tried:

```
.app-cta-button .tx-button.ios { 
    display: none !important;
}
```

but it doesn´t work and the buttons still show.

The website is: [allipossess.tumblr.com](http://allipossess.tumblr.com) but I guess many people will have that problem with their Tumblr when switching off the custom mobile theme by Tumblr...

[screenshot of the two Tumblr buttons that appear on iPhone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZ3e1.png)

Comment: Have you tried disabling “promote tumblr” in the advanced options in the customise theme menu?

Comment: Yes, that´s the first thing I did.

Comment: This is what I use `iframe[class^="tmblr-iframe"] {display:none;}`

Comment: @lharby I´m afraid that also doesn´t do the trick for me. It always works in the preview in chrome, but when I safe it in the css file, it still always comes back.

Comment: If you’re talking about the tumblr app I would be amazed if it’s possible. If you’re talking about viewing the site in safari on a mobile then I think it’s possible

Comment: @lharby I´m talking about safari on a mobile and after trying what you said, you can trust me when I say it doesn´t work. See my answer below for part of the fix.

Comment: @SimonFreund I don't doubt it. I had real problems trying to remove mine. My suspicion was the content was being added by javascript, with some timeout, or even being called by a back end service. So I initially tried a js solution myself, which did not work. I was surprised that a pure css solution did work for me, but my theme is highly modified. I will try and take a look at your site later (tumblr is blocked from work annoyingly).

Comment: @SimonFreund well it's a mystery as it looks fine on my iphone (5). https://imgur.com/a/cW9bR. If you have Safari on a mac in developer mode you can plug the device via the USB and then inspect the browser and see the code that is running on the device. It's a bit blind, but I suspect the iframe is using fixed positioning. If the top and right parameters are set, then it would be possible to add `right:-1000px` or `bottom: -1000px` or some other large offset or maybe change the `z-index`.  One other thing, it's not fixed but still cached on your phone? Sorry I can't be of more help.

Answer (score 1):

I now made the "Get the Tumblr App" button disappear by using `.app-cta-button { opacity: 0 !important; }` so seems 'opacity' is accepted but 'display' or 'visibility' not... The top bar with: "Open in the Tumblr App" is still showing though.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.tmblr-iframe--app-cta-button {
    display: none!important;
}

.tmblr-iframe-compact .tmblr-iframe--unified-controls {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Nick. Welcome to StackOverflow! While your code might solve OP's problem, you should explain why your code solves the problem. This will make the answer more valuable in the long run.